# How to implement linear interpolation in Matlab - Coordinates and dates

Tags: matlab, date, time, coordinates, interpolation

I have a CSV file contains data of Hurricane location coordinates. 
I'm new to Matlab so I'm not sure how to treat correctly date and hour cells, especially when they are displayed unconventionally.

I need to apply linear interpolation so I can get the date for every 30 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you read the data in as numerical values

Now you have some matrix like so:

```
data = [20130928    0  21.1 50.0
        20130928  600  22.2 50.3
        20130928 1200  23.3 50.6
        20130928 1800  24.2 50.6];
```

To convert the first two columns to `datetime` values, we could do this:

```
% Concatenate first two columns, including making all times 4 digits by 0 padding
fulltime = [num2str(data(:,1)), num2str(data(:,2), '%.4u')]
% Use datetime to convert (cell) times to dates with given format
dates = datetime(cellstr(fulltime),'inputformat', 'yyyyMMddHHmm');

>> dates = 28-Sep-2013 00:00:00
           28-Sep-2013 06:00:00
           28-Sep-2013 12:00:00
           28-Sep-2013 18:00:00
```

Now we can easily interpolate. First [create an array of times](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time.html) we want to use:

```
% Data value every 30 mins
interpdates = dates(1):hours(0.5):dates(end)
```

Then use `interp1`

```
interpolateddata = interp1(dates, data(:,3:4), interpdates);
>> interpolateddata = 21.1000   50.0000
                      21.1917   50.0250
                      21.2833   50.0500
                      21.3750   50.0750
                      ...
                      24.1250   50.6000
                      24.2000   50.6000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it was very useful!

Comment: Click the green / white tick under the voting arrows in the top-left corner of the answer, thanks